# Can I add non-persistent fields to a model?

Tags: objection.js

Is there a recommended practice for adding non-persistent attributes to an Objection model object such that it that won't overwrite predefined attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objection models have the [virtualAttributes](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#virtualattributes) field. From the documentation:

> The virtual values are not written to database. Only the “external” JSON format will contain them.

It is important to note these are functions, not just model properties.

Example from the docs:

```
class Person extends Model {
  static get virtualAttributes() {
    return ['fullName', 'isFemale'];
  }

  fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  get isFemale() {
    return this.gender === 'female';
  }
}

const person = Person.fromJson({
  firstName: 'Jennifer',
  lastName: 'Aniston',
  gender: 'female'
});

console.log(person.toJSON());
// --> {"firstName": "Jennifer", "lastName": "Aniston", "isFemale": true, "fullName": "Jennifer Aniston"}
```